# Wrong UFT-8 encode using SqlJetDb in Java and SQLite3

Tags: java, utf-8, sqlite

I'm trying to save data into a SQLite3 file, all work perfect but when I check the data I have problems with the UTF-8 encode, some characters are saved wrong. For example:

...412|1|Jos�|Rodr�guez|0...

I expected:

...412|1|José|Rodróguez|0...

I have tried with:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(string)
```

But with no results

```
    /* Log */
    try {
        File dbFile = new File("log.db");
        SqlJetDb db = SqlJetDb.open(dbFile, true);
        db.beginTransaction(SqlJetTransactionMode.WRITE);
        ISqlJetTable table = db.getTable("apikeys");
        table.insertOr(SqlJetConflictAction.REPLACE,key, 1, Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(names), Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(lastnames), phone, Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(email));
        db.commit();
        db.close();
    } catch (SqlJetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: SQLite expects all strings to be in UTF-8, and does not convert them. The problem must be that you're using some other encoding somewhere. How exactly are you writing the data? What is the output of `SELECT hex(NameColumn) FROM MyTable` for such a record?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have tried your command and I get only the hex values of the strings: "4D6172696120..."

Comment: Character encoding errors are hard to diagnose because the error can be in many places. How are you so sure it's stored wrong? Maybe there's something wrong in the way you are reading or displaying the data (for example, using the wrong character encoding while reading or displaying).

Comment: @AlejandroQH That command is supposed to show hex values. Show those values for a 'wrong' record.

Comment: ok I understand, but I have tried to read the data bases with CLI, with Valentina Studio  and DB Browser for SQL, and the same results.